# Why am i getting output for permutations of a string of length only 3?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, data-structures, permutation

Print Permutations - String

Given a string, find and print all the possible permutations of the input string.
Note : The order of permutations are not important. Just print them in different lines.

> Sample Input :
>
> abc
>
> Sample Output :
>
> abc acb bac bca cab cba

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printCurrentString(string input, string result, int count[], int level)
{
    if (level == input.size())
    {
        cout << result << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        {
            if (count[i] == 0)
                continue;
            else
            {
                result[level] = input[i];
                count[i]--;
                printCurrentString(input, result, count, level + 1);
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printPermutations(string input)
{
    char *result = new char[input.size()];
    int *count = new int[input.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        count[i] = 1;
    printCurrentString(input, result, count, 0);
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    printPermutations(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code leads to *undefined behavior*. Your call to `printCurrentString` creates a `std::string` object for the `result` argument, but this construction is created with the C-style null-terminated byte string `result` in `printPermutations`. The problem is that in `printPermutations` the null-terminated byte string `result` ***isn't*** null-terminated. The memory you allocate will have *indeterminate* values, and using it in any way (like initializing a `std::string` object) leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: So how do i resolve that ?

Comment: one way: make ```result``` one char larger and put ```\0``` into the last position. Also your post seems not to mention why you wrote it. What is your problem?

Comment: it works only I give string of input size 3(abc) but it fails when i give input of other sizes like 2(ab) or 4(abcd).

Comment: The C++ standard library has facilities that can be used to loop over all permutations of elements of a container.  A `std::string` is such a container.  No need to dynamically create arrays at all - it is possible to obtain all permutations be setting up  single container, then looping over all permutations of its elements,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two major problems, both leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

First from the `printPermutations` function:

```
char *result = new char[input.size()];
```

As mentioned in my comment, this will allocate memory but not initialize it in any way. Creating a `std::string` from this memory is one cause of UB (Undefined Behavior).

The second is in the `printCurrentString` function, where you have

```
result[level] = input[i];
```

Since you don't know the actual size of the the string in `result` you don't know if `level` is a valid index. It could be out of bounds. Indexing out of bounds also leads to UB.

You can solve both of these issues with a simple change: In the `printPermutations` function don't create the result string dynamically the way you do. Instead create a proper `std::string` object of the correct length and pass it:

```
printCurrentString(input, string(input.length()), count, 0);
```

---

And considering the memory leaks you have (you don't `delete[]` the memory you `new[]`) I would also recommend you use a `std::vector<int>` for `count`, and that you pass this vector by reference.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/We2L2cSr 
Thanks mate. Really Appreciate It.Is this what you meant ?